# Call method in parallel with CompletablFuture and ExecutorService

Tags: java-8, executorservice, completable-future

I am trying to make parallel calls to `getPrice` method, for each `product` in `products`. I have this piece of code and verified that getPrice is running in separate threads, but they are running sequentially, not in parallel. Can anyone please point me to what am I missing here?

Thanks a lot for your help.

```
   ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_POOL_SIZE);
   Set<Product> decoratedProductSet = products.stream()
   .map(product -> CompletableFuture
                             .supplyAsync(() -> getPrice(product.getId(), date, context), service))
   .map(t -> t.exceptionally(throwable -> null))
   .map(t -> t.join())
   .collect(Collectors.<Product>toSet());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are streaming your products, sending each of to a `CompletableFuture` but then wait for it with join, before the stream processes the next one.

Why not use:

```
products.parallelStream()
 .map(p -> getPrice(p.getId(), date, context))
 .collect(Collectors.<Product>toSet());
```